# Can a <p> tag in <a> tag?

Tags: css, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is putting a div inside an anchor ever correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct)

When we write some kind of 'product list', you need only one link, but it should contain product image, product name, product title etc. can we use a contain p or some other tag? is there any cross browser issue?

I heard in html5, a tag can contain p tag, but still with no confidence about using it.

some code like so:

```
<ul class="xxx_list">  
<li class="hproduct">  
    <a href="#" class="url" title="" target="_blank">  
        <img class="photo" src="shoujike.jpg" alt="手机壳">  
        <p>  
            <span class="price_wrap">&yen;<span class="price">88.00</span</span>  
            <span class="fav">收藏</span>  
        </p>  
        <p><a class="fn" href="">基本商品单元的商品名称</a></p>  
    </a>  
</li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes you can, why shouldn't you?

Comment: Well you have an `<a>` within a `<p>` within an `<a>` - that's obviously not allowed.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct)

Comment: so, just display:block, then everthing is OK?

Comment: Firefox 3.6 is about the most recent browser to have a problem with this.

Comment: Here also is `<p/>` inside `<a/>` and additionally `<hgroup/>` directly inside `<body/>`. Why not?... Looks like DHTMLX. see source: https://whatwg.org/. Do not put html block/table elements inside inline elements. Use `<span/>` because it is not kosher to put block inside inline elements and backward incompatible.

Answer (score 28):

In HTML 4.x (and earlier) and XHTML 1.x — No. `<a>` elements may not contain `<p>` elements.

In HTML 5 — `<a>` elements may contain `<p>` elements, but browsers are a bit flaky about it and you may find you have to explicitly set the `<a>` to `display: block` in your stylesheet.

The code in the question also includes an `<a>` inside that `<p>`. This is not allowed. An `<a>` element may not be a descendant of another `<a>` element.

Comment: It is weird and it shall be forbidden. html block element inside inline element. I can understand block inside inline-block but not inside inline... Then... `<table/>` can be inside `<a/>` tag in html5?

Comment: Don't confuse CSS display styles with the HTML 4 grouping of elements into "block" and "inline" (which no longer exists in HTML 5).

Comment: I don't confuse it. I comment it due HTML4 definition of "inline and block" elements. The idea of HTML5 is backward compatibility with HTML4. In HTML4 is the `<p/>` "inline" element to be able put it into `<a/>`?

Comment: HTML 5 is backwards compatible in the sense that (almost) anything you can do in HTML 4 you can also do in HTML 5. The reverse is not true.

Comment: Thus... the HTML5 site can be badly shown in old browsers... Part of old browsers badly interpret the "block" elements inside "inline" elements. "inline-block" I named here `<button/>` element.

Answer (score 5):

Inside `a` tag can be tags with default `display: inline` or `inline-block`. tags like `span`, `em`, `strong` etc.

You can change your `p` to `span` with some class and write some styles in CSS for this class.

P.S.: You can't use `a` inside `a`.

UPDATE:

```
<ul class="xxx_list">  
    <li class="hproduct">  
        <a href="#" class="url" title="" target="_blank">  
            <img class="photo" src="shoujike.jpg" alt="手机壳">  
            <span class="some-class-name">  
                <span class="price_wrap">&yen;<span class="price">88.00</span</span>  
                <span class="fav">收藏</span>  
            </span>  
            <span class="fn">基本商品单元的商品名称</span>  
        </a>  
    </li>  
</ul>
```