# anchor tag not working using preg_replace

Tags: javascript, php, kohana, kohana-3

views.php

```
 <a href="<?= URL::site(); ?>feeds/view/<?php echo $feed->feed_id; ?>"> 
 <p class="feed-text" style="word-wrap:break-word;">
     <?php if($feed_text = preg_replace('!(http|ftp|scp)(s)?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9.=?&_/]+!', "<a style=text-decoration:underline;color:blue href=\"\\0\" target='_blank' >\\0</a>",$feed->feed_text)):
     echo nl2br($feed_text);
     else:
     echo nl2br($feed->feed_text); endif;?>
 </p>
 </a>
```

The above view code is to show the text and url. If user post only text,the else part will work and if user post text along with you tube url the first condition works.

If user post text,on clicking that text will take user to another page.This also applies if user post both text with you tube url also.Here on clicking the text,should take him to next screen.

Problem is,if user post text along with you tube url and if the you tube url is present between the text,the text after you tube url is losing the anchor tag.But,if the post contain you tube link after the text(after end of text),the anchor tag is working correctly.

example of issue:

Ten little monkeys jumping on the bed . . . and tripping over teddy bears, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38hnsgqf8O0 slipping on banana peels, and falling off the dock!

After "slipping on banana peels, and falling off the dock!" anchor tag is not working.Rest of the other cases working fine.

How to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `display:block;` style to the anchor tag:

```
<a style="display:block;" href="<?= URL::site(); ?>feeds/view/<?php echo $feed->feed_id; ?>">
```

It is correct only in HTML5 (See [Can a <p> tag in <a> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911274/can-a-p-tag-in-a-tag))

But whan a user adds a url inside the text, then it cannot be done this way. An `<a>` element may not be a descendant of another `<a>` element.

However, there is a way to do this. You can split the text by inserted urls and wrap each of the parts inside the `<a>` wrapper. So the html will have the structure like:

```
<p>
  <a href="<?= URL::site(); ?>feeds/view/<?php echo $feed->feed_id; ?>">
    text_part_1
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38hnsgqf8O0">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38hnsgqf8O0</a>
  <a href="<?= URL::site(); ?>feeds/view/<?php echo $feed->feed_id; ?>">
    text_part_2
  </a>      
</p>
```