# HTML hyperlinks are merging with other paragraph tags

Tags: html

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
<title>Abbas Maheryar - Inquiries</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><h1>Inquiries</h1></center>
<h3><u>Use this information to contact me</u></h3>
<div>
<center><p><b>Phone:</b=> 818-857-0846
<p><b>Email:</b></p><a href="mailto:abbasmaheryar@gmail.com?Subject=Service Inquiry"target="_top"><p>abbasmaheryar@gmail.com</p>
</center>
</div>
<div>
<p>Inquiries</p> | <a href="./news.html"><p>News</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that when i try to link my email, it also links Inquiries down at the bottom. What can i do to fix this?

Comment: Please add the theme.css too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semantically correct HTML should look like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
  <title>Abbas Maheryar - Inquiries</title>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <h1>Inquiries</h1>
  </center>
  <h3><u>Use this information to contact me</u></h3>
  <div>
    <center>
      <p>
        <b>Phone:</b> 818-857-0846
      </p>
      <p>
        <b>Email:</b>
        <a href="mailto:abbasmaheryar@gmail.com?Subject=Service Inquiry" target="_top">
        abbasmaheryar@gmail.com
        </a>
      </p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      Inquiries | <a href="./news.html">News</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your hyperlinks are running together, because you have forgotten to **close** your email hyperlink with **`</a>`**.

```
<a href="mailto:abbasmaheryar@gmail.com?Subject=Service Inquiry"target="_top"><p>abbasmaheryar@gmail.com</p></a>
```

You also need to close your news hyperlink, which will cause the same problem with any proceeding hyperlinks. This needs closing as well:

```
<a href="./news.html"><p>News</p></a>
```

Also note that `<p>` tags should **not** got within `<a>` tags, as this is unsupported markup in HTML4, and [**flaky in HTML5**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13911331/2341603). Instead, you should move your paragraphs to the outside of your links, and structure your two blocks of code like this:

```
<p><a href="mailto:abbasmaheryar@gmail.com?Subject=Service Inquiry"target="_top">abbasmaheryar@gmail.com</a></p>
<p><a href="./news.html">News</a></p>
```

The full markup you are looking for is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
  <title>Abbas Maheryar - Inquiries</title>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <h1>Inquiries</h1>
  </center>
  <h3><u>Use this information to contact me</u></h3>
  <div>
    <center>
      <p><b>Phone:</b> 818-857-0846
      <p><b>Email:</b></p>
      <p>
        <a href="mailto:abbasmaheryar@gmail.com?Subject=Service Inquiry" target="_top">
        abbasmaheryar@gmail.com</a>
      </p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Inquiries</p> |
    <p>
      <a href="./news.html">News</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps! :)